# running a linear regresion using r in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am trying really hard to undestand how tableau and r works together.

```
SCRIPT_REAL("mydata <- data.frame(cbind([Exports]=.arg1,
             [Crop Year]=.arg2,
             [Calendar Date]=.arg3,)); 
             fit <- lm(Exports ~.,data=mydata")
```

The following error I receive:

> Script real is being called with string.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are all of your arguments numeric?
Especially, Calendar Date may be string in R.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something like this

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Exports=.arg1, Crop_Year=.arg2, Calendar_Date=.arg3));
fit <- lm(Exports ~ Crop_Year + Calendar_Date, data=mydata)',
[tableau_Exports_columnname],[tableau_CropYear_columnname],[tableau_CalendarDate_columnname])
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: Since Script_Real is a table calc, you also need to define the partitioning and addressing dimensions to specify how to block up the data to send to R (i.e. one large vector, a series of small vectors etc) Right click on your calc pill and edit Table Calc. If you are lucky the default settings will work as desired, but in general you should specify these settings (aka "compute using"). See the online help